# Are these two lines written in swift 4 the same?

Tags: ios, swift

I got a deprecation warning on this line:

```
components.append("-b \"\(string.substring(to: string.index(before: string.endIndex)))\"")
```

So I changed it to:

```
components.append("-b \"\(String(string[..<string.endIndex]) )\"")
```

Is the second line okay?, because my code otherwise seems to be working fine.

Comment: Actually that's what Playgrounds (and Tests) are for.  Prove it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see

```
let string = "12345"
var components = [String]()
var components2 = [String]()

components.append("-b \"\(string.substring(to: string.index(before: string.endIndex)))\"")
components2.append("-b \"\(String(string[..<string.endIndex]) )\"")

print(components)
print(components2)
print(components == components2)
```

gives us

```
["-b \"1234\""]
["-b \"12345\""]
false
```

so the answer is, no they are not...

If your intention is to remove the last character, then you can just use `dropLast`:

```
components.append("-b \"\(string.dropLast())\"")
```

note that you can pass a param for the number of elements you want to drop (`dropLast(2)` for example)

Finally, the equivalent expression after using the partial range would be:

```
string[..<string.index(before: string.endIndex)]
```

and that is because the first expression translates to:

> The index up to but not including the index *before* the endIndex

while the second one translates to:

> The index up to but not including the endIndex

where endIndex refers to the "past the end" position